# SSRS parameters based on previous parameter

Tags: reporting-services, filter, parameters

In my report I have a parameter which allows the user to choose one or multi-options.

```
Driver 1,
Driver 2,
Driver 3
```

I have another parameter that would only be valid if they chose Driver 3 from the previous parameter.

```
AAA,
BBB,
CCC
```

So maybe the user would choose Driver 1 and Driver 3 and then choose BBB. How can I have the report provide all the data for Driver 1 and only BBB for Driver 3?

Comment: How are you loading your values? If using multi pick it's best to join the params into a comma deliminated string, then  split it in the second params loading sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the lists of parameter values coming from the database? If so you can use the result of the first parameter to filter the query for the second.
For example. If we wanted to be able to select from a list of geographical regions and then from there choose from a list of countries that exist in those regions we could do something like this.

Create a new dataset called say dsRegions and get a list of regions from the database with something like

```
SELECT RegionID, RegionName From dbo.Regions
```

Create a new parameter @regions and set it to be multi-value and set the available values to be from a dataset. select dsRegions and use the ID column as the value and name column as the label.

Create another dataset say dsCountries but this time the query will look something like this.

```
SELECT CountryID, CountryName FROM dbo.Countries WHERE RegionID IN (@regions)
```

***Note: It is important to use IN (@regions) and not = @regions or the query will fail when more than one region is selected.***

Create a new parameter @countries, set it up as we did with the previous parameter but this time pointing it at dsCountries

This way, anytime the user selects a new region or regions, the @regions parameter is updated, then the countries list will be re-queried and populated.

Finally, the @countries parameter would be passed to the main dataset for the report.

Assuming your 1st and 2nd parameters have a similar relationship then you should be able to adapt this generic example easily.